# What phase of matter is shaving cream?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, phase

Our teacher asked us if shaving cream is a solid, liquid, or gas. She didn't quite know herself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is toothpaste solid or liquid?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23899/is-toothpaste-solid-or-liquid)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shaving cream is a special type of mixture called a [colloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloid), consisting of tiny air bubbles dispersed in liquid. This particular type of colloid can further classified as a [foam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foam). Since the mixture itself consists of two distinct phases, it doesn't really make sense to classify the entire mixture as one phase. If you *had* to pick one though, it is most nearly a liquid since that is the dispersion medium.